# Plotting and graphing $x^2 +y^2+ e^{z^2} =10$

Tags: geometry, analysis, graphing-functions, surfaces

In an exercise from an analysis book, I came across a new set.

What can I say about the subset of $\mathbb R^3$ described by the equation $x^2 +y^2+ e^{z^2} =10$?. Let A be this set.

The function $f:x^2 +y^2+ e^{z^2}$ from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R$ is continuous and A is closed because it is the preimage of a closed set (the set {10}.
It is bounded because $0\le x^2 + y^2 \le 9$ and $0\le z ^2 \le ln(10)$. So it is a compact set.
The set is symmetric with respect to the variables $x, y, z $, in the sense that $x\in A$ if and only if $-x \in A$, and the same holds for y and z.
If we fix a certain value for z, we have a circumference $x^2 +y^2=10-e^{z^2}$, its center being (0,0,z).
So it seems to me quite similar to an ellipsoid. However, should the exponential "kind of" make a difference?

Do you have any suggestions on how to draw it? Or do you know where to find a graph of this surface?

Comment: not a sphere, but it is a smooth surface of revolution bounding a convex set. Start with $x^2 + e^{(z^2)}= 10 $   with is a curve in the plane ($xz$)

Comment: Why don't you attempt to write the equation under the form $z=...$ ?

Comment: +1 Interesting question, nicely presented.  Personally, I wouldn't go near trying to graph this complicated 3-dim problem *manually*, but would instead opt for computer assistance.  In the *latex to pdf* genre (re https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX), you have PSTricks, PGF-Tikz, Asymptote, ...  Although I am unfamiliar with non-latex approaches, there are other (free) similar software packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plot this with Mathematica and probably most any other language with graphics:

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + Exp[z^2] == 10, {x, -3.5, 3.5}, {y, -3.5, 3.5}, {z, -3.5,3.5}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 nicely done.  Do you think that it is *tacky* to be that adroit?

Comment: Not any more uncouth than using a couple of words I had to look up to understand.

Comment: Besides, this answer would get at most a few yawns at the Mathematica Stack Exchange.  Maybe also a few minus ones.

Comment: Interesting point.  I stand corrected; I guess you're not adroit, based on your *adroit* argument.  Oh wait, I'm trapped in a paradox.

Comment: Adroit yes, tacky no.  Hope that gets you out of your bind!

Comment: Anyway, just kidding, as am sure you are too!

Answer (score 1):

A surface of revolution made flatter along $z$ axis like dutch cheese stock.  Otherwise cylindrical.

$$ z= \sqrt{ \log(10-r^2)}$$